# Fake location AND speed in emulator. KML or GPX?

Tags: android

I figured how to connect emulator + IntelliJ + DDMS all together and I can spoof GPS location fine.

I figured how to generate KML and GPX files.

Issue I have:
1. KML file I generate using google maps doesn't have speed info.
2. GPX files won't even open in DDMS

Ideally I'd like to solve my problem with either KML or GPX (I don't care which format to use) but I need to feed coordinates and speed into emulator.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far no responses :)

Here is what I found myself. The only way (as far as I see it) to pass speed into emulator is to use Telnet and pass command like this:

```
geo nmea $GPRMC,040302.663,A,3939.7,N,10506.6,W,0.27,358.86,200804,,*1A
```

Only GPRMC format can carry speed and other goodies.

Now I needed better way to pass steps to my application. Since my main tool is C# - I just wrote simple telnet client, put it into test class and voila! Now I get step by step GPS spoofing on emulator. I can use any source and then pass it into emulator for replay.

Comment: So sad that there isn't another way!  Thanks so much for finding this though!  I've got positions but with no speed data due to the KML source and its not triggering my code that depends on speed.  Thanks for the question and answer!

Answer (score 0):

The `geo fix` command now supports velocity:

```
'geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude> [<satellites> [<velocity>]]]'
 allows you to send a simple GPS fix to the emulated system.
 The parameters are:

  <longitude>   longitude, in decimal degrees
  <latitude>    latitude, in decimal degrees
  <altitude>    optional altitude in meters
  <satellites>  number of satellites being tracked (1-12)
  <velocity>    optional velocity in knots
```